# Am I hardcoding?

Tags: java, hardcoded

I am a new CS major and I'm struggling to understand some of the concepts, particularly hardcoding.

If I have a program such as the following, is this hardcoding?

Apologies if I did not ask the question properly

```
public class Dictionary {
enum Book {
        Noun1("Book [noun] : A set of pages."),
        Noun2("Book [noun] : A written work published in printed or electronic form."),
        Verb1("Book [verb] : To arrange for someone to have a seat on a plane."),
        Verb2("Book [verb] : To arrange something on a particular date.");
        private String value;

        Book(String s) { this.value = s; }

        public String getValue() { return value; }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> bookList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Book bookValues : Book.values()) {
        bookList.add(bookValues.getDefinition());

    Map<String, Object> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    dictionary.put("book",bookList); 

    }
```

Comment: Note that it's not a great usage of enum. Your logic is the same for all enums, so it should be dictionary of some kind. Enums should be used when you have different logic for each case.

Answer (score 3):

Hard-coding is when data is encapsulated in your code. So, yes, especially with the relatively large amount of information in the enum, this would qualify.

An alternative would be storing data outside of the code (e.g., in a text file) and loading that data in your code.

So, in your sample code, you could move dictionary definitions to a file and then load it during runtime. Then the data would no longer be hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

If you review the [strict definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding), any data embedded in your code rather than being stored externally to your program is hard-coding. So you could make the case that you are indeed hard-coding as there are strings in your `enum` definition for example.

In my view, in terms of standard practice, it's not unreasonable for values in `enums` and other static data to be present in your code. You should make use of constants to give meaning to constant data. For example, rather than:

```
int rate = 60;
```

use:

```
static final int CYCLES_PER_SECOND = 60;
...
int rate = CYCLES_PER_SECOND;
```

Reviewing your code, I'd leave the `enum` alone, but perhaps you need to explain the first key `"book"` in your `dictionary`.

Comment: On the other hand, people do insane things like "int MILLISECONDS_IN_ONE_SECOND = 1000".  This is going too far.  You can multiply your 'time in seconds' by a literal 1000 to convert seconds to milliseconds. At least until the international standard units people decide that they prefer that a millisecond is 1/998th of a second.  The matter, as usual, is not about hard and fast rules, but about what is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think basically to answer your question. Imagine that you are producing a package after building that code; like a war file.

The key question is that: "If I need to change the value of one of my variables, (For example; a "Book-noun" sentence in your code), should I need to reproduce my package?"

If you really need to produce package every time; yes, you are hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

This code use is limited to the data present inside your class. This is hard coding.